# Replace iterator at the end of string

Tags: c#, string

For a file function I added an iterator the the new name of the file.

The names will look like this:

- My Name
- My Name (1)
- My Name (2)
- ...
- My Name (10)

For finding the next "available" number I'm using a while loop:

```
while (Stuff.FindNameByText(text) != null)
{
    text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", text, i.ToString());
    i++;
}
File.SetNewName(text)
```

But this code of course gives me the following output:

- My name
- My name (1)
- My name (1) (2)
- ...

How do I first add an iterator the strings end (if not existing) - and otherwise replace the existing one. I did the following, but it would end in an infinite loop...

```
while (Stuff.FindNameByText(text) != null)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("\\{0}.*?\\{1}", "(", ")"));
    text = regex.IsMatch(text, i.ToString());
    File.SetNewName(text)
}
```

Maybe someone could help me out a bit. If iterator at the end is not existing - add one, otherwise replace existing one with new number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var orig = text;

while (Stuff.FindNameByText(text) != null)
{
    text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", orig, i.ToString());
    i++;
}
File.SetNewName(text)
```