# The parsing of FolderBrowserDialog doesn't work ask expected

Tags: c#

```
int index = 0;
while (true)
{
    index = fd.SelectedPath.IndexOf("D"); // never get to the if index -1 to check why !
    if (index == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    string sub = fd.SelectedPath.Substring(index, 2);
}
```

sub is `D:` if i select the path D in the browser.
This is good i want to get only the `D:`
But its never getting out the loop its keep looping without stop.

Why it doesn't get into the -1 if?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace iterator at the end of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769928/replace-iterator-at-the-end-of-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each iteration the `indexOf()` method will starts search from the begining of string so you need to set `startIndex` parameter or you can use  `System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(path)` method.

```
int index = -1;
while (true)
{
 index = fd.SelectedPath.IndexOf("D",index+1); 
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
 index = fd.SelectedPath.IndexOf("D", index+1);
```

and that requires initializing index at -1, not 0

Answer (score 1):

> This is good i want to get only the D:

Don't parse this yourself, use the System.IO.Path class instead.  This will then help you take care of cases where the user selected a network share.  Like this:

```
        var root = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(fd.SelectedPath);
        if (root.Length == 3 && root[1] == ':') {
            // Got an actual drive letter, not a UNC path
            string drive = root.SubString(0, 2);
            // etc..
        }
```